# Azure Devops UnitTest Could not find file "bin\Release\net6.0\GetEnterpriseIdFromXML.xml"

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, devops, .net-6.0

System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path ....bin\Release\net6.0\GetEnterpriseIdFromXML.xml

I keep this file in my solutions directory, and locally, the test case is running fine, but after deployment, this file is not generating into the bin\release\net6.0 folder.

From my solution file (.csproj) configuration. Am I missing something?

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="bin\Debug\net6.0\GetEnterpriseIdFromXML.xml" />
    <Content Include="bin\Debug\net6.0\UnumGetPartyResponse.xml" /> 
    <Content Include="bin\Release\net6.0\GetEnterpriseIdFromXML.xml" /> 
    <Content Include="bin\Release\net6.0\UnumGetPartyResponse.xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Where should I change so that GetEnterpriseIdFromXML.xml will be moved to the bin\Release\net6.0 folder?

Comment: in which folder need to keep this file GetEnterpriseIdFromXML.xml that moved to bin folder while run/build solution?

Comment: If you are building on a Linux agent, then you're probably using the wrong path, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73429997/azure-pipeline-and-microsoft-tests-with-files-is-not-working.