# Write a file in a JUnit test under resources folder

Tags: java, maven, junit, io

I'd already tried with [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400243/what-is-the-correct-way-to-write-to-temp-file-during-unit-tests-with-maven) but I'm a little bit lost with maven.

In a Maven project I want to test a function which finally writes a text file in the given path. The signature of my function is `boolean printToFile(String absolutePath)` (the returning value is a success flag)

Under `src/test/resources` I have my expected file; lets call it `expected.txt`.

Using the `apache.commons.commons-io` dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I want to call my function; create two `File` objects and compare their content:

```
@Test
public void fileCreationTest() {
  String outputPath = Thread.currentThread().getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("got.txt").getFile();
  myTestedObject.printToFile(outputPath);
  File got = new File(outputPath);

  String expectedFilePath = Thread.currentThread().getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("expected.txt").getFile();
  File expected = new File(expectedFilePath)

  boolean areEqual = FileUtils.contentEquals(got, expected);
  Assert.assertTrue(areEqual);
```

[EDITED]
It's not a matter of the calling function: **If I call it from normal code, it does work** But If I run my test, it fails (from maven or from my IDE). I think it's something related with *the test nature*.

Comment: Also, if you visually inspect the files by hand, are they the same?

Comment: Wait a minute, are you saying that if you run the test in your IDE, it works, but it doesn't work with `mvn test`?

Comment: Yes, it's a typo. Editing for all these questions (trying to make it more clear)

Comment: Post the code of your tested method. My guess is that it has an encoding issue.

Comment: It does work if you call it from normal code; I promise :) It calls so many private functions which are not related with the issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code makes no sense to me (in a test or otherwise):

```
String outputPath = Thread.currentThread().getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("got.txt").getFile();
myTestedObject.printToFile(outputPath);
File got = new File(outputPath);
```

The problem is that `getResource` will return a `URL` to a resource that might be on the file system, in a JAR or other place. And it must exist for `getResource` to return non-`null`. That means your test will need to overwrite it (and it is probably not writable).

What you probably should do instead, is:

```
File got = File.createTempFile("got-", ".txt");
String outputPath = got.getAbsolutePath();
myTestedObject.printToFile(outputPath);
```

Also, for the `expected` file, I think it's better if you use the test class' class loader, rather than the context class loader. It's also more readable:

```
String expectedFilePath = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("expected.txt").getFile();
File expected = new File(expectedFilePath);
```

However, again you make the assumption that the resource is loaded from the file system. So it might break if it isn't. Can you compare the bytes from two `InputStream`s instead?

Finally, make sure that the test writes the file with the same encoding as the your expected file, and that linefeeds/carriage returns match.

Comment: Implemented, is there any way to inspect the temporal file?

Comment: @manutero Sure. Print its path and open it in an external tool, or print its content from the test.