# What does @Rule do?

Tags: java, junit, rule

When trying to make a temporary file for unit tests I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12400605/4714970) that mentioned  "TemporaryFolder JUnit @Rule" and a [link](https://garygregory.wordpress.com/2010/01/20/junit-tip-use-rules-to-manage-temporary-files-and-folders/) explaining how to use it. Which is like this:

```
@Rule
public TemporaryFolder testFolder = new TemporaryFolder();
```

and then `testFolder.newFile("file.txt")`

My question is what does the @Rule annotation do?

Removing the annotation doesn't appear to actually change anything.

Answer (score 7):

As the documentation of [`Rule`](http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/Rule.html) and [`TemporaryFolder`](http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/rules/TemporaryFolder.html) states, it takes care of creating a temporary directory before each test method of the respective class and deleting this temporary folder (and its content) after each test method.

You can write your own rules easily by implementing [`TestRule`](http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/rules/TestRule.html) or [`MethodRule`](http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/rules/MethodRule.html) or extending from any of its implementing classes like [`ExternalResource`](http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/rules/ExternalResource.html).

The same logic could be guaranteed with `@Before` and `@After` annotated initialization and cleanup methods. However, you would need to add the logic right into the test-class. If you need the logic in multiple test-classes, you either need to use inheritance, write some arbitrary utility-classes or externalize the behavior. Rules do exactly the latter one by allowing you to re-use this kind of initialization or cleanup-logic and furthermore reduce the code and remove unneeded code so that the focus is on the actual test rather than the configuration of some directories or servers.

[This project](https://github.com/mjeanroy/junit-servers) for example declares two kind of servers (Jetty or Tomcat) you just have to annotate with `@Rule` in order to use the server for integration or end-to-end tests.

If you want to initialize a rule only once for all test-methods, simply replace `@Rule` with `@ClassRule` and initialize the rule as `public static`. This will initialize the class rule only once and will be reused for each test-method.

```
@ClassRule
public static JettyServerRule server = new JettyServerRule(new EmbeddedJetty());

@Test
public void myUnitTest() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String url = String.format("http://localhost:%s", server.getPort());

    String response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);

    assertEquals("Hello World", response);
}
```

The above sample would initialize a Jetty server only once and each test method of the test-class can reuse this server instead of starting and tearing down a new server for each method.

Multiple rules can even be combined with [`RuleChain`](http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/rules/RuleChain.html):

```
@Rule
public RuleChain chain= RuleChain.outerRule(new LoggingRule("outer rule")
                                 .around(new LoggingRule("middle rule")
                                 .around(new LoggingRule("inner rule");
```

In one of our integration-tests, which sent a couple of requests simultaneously to our JAX-RS service deployed via Restlet on Jetty we have the following rule-definitions:

```
public static SpringContextRule springContextRule;
public static RestletServerRule restletServer;

static {
    springContextRule = new SpringContextRule(JaxRsRestletTestSpringConfig.class);
    restletServer = new RestletServerRule(springContextRule.getSpringContext());
}

@ClassRule
public static RuleChain ruleChain = RuleChain.outerRule(restletServer).around(springContextRule);

// Tempus Fugit rules
@Rule
public ConcurrentRule concurrently = new ConcurrentRule();

@Rule
public RepeatingRule repeatedly = new RepeatingRule();
```

Which initializes a spring annotation context before the Restlet/Jetty server is started to enable Spring bean injection. Furthermore, the Tempus Fugit rules are utilized to execute test methods a couple of times concurrently in order to spot race-conditions and concurrency related problems earlier.