# how to give test resources file path in config.properties file

Tags: java

I have a file`(Ex:test.txt)` in `src/test/resources`, I have `config.properties` file in same location `(src/test/resources)`. In `config.properties` file I have a property `file_path`, to this property I have to pass path of `test.txt` file.
How to pass that value?

I tried with

```
file_path=${basedir}/src/test/resources/test.txt
file_path=/src/test/resources/test.txt
file_path=../src/test/resources/test.txt
file_path=test.txt
```

But none of them are working

Comment: What IDE are you using? What are you using your test.txt for?
Maybe you could use a temporary file to fit your need in your unit-test:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400243/what-is-the-correct-way-to-write-to-temp-file-during-unit-tests-with-maven

Comment: I am using Eclipse IDE, actually during test run  , I am creating that file and after test deleting the file also...

Comment: Then I would definitely look in the link I sent above, it shows whats best practice for files in unit-tests. Either that or you run unit tests from the console instead from Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed

```
file_path=/src/test/resources/test.txt
```

To

```
file_path=src\\test\\resources\\test.txt
```

Then It worked